# Can I bring candy into Canada

Tags: canada, food-and-drink

We plan a single say trip to my sister in laws house in Windsor. Can I bring cookies or candies across the border. We are coming from Michigan through the Windsor tunnel.

Comment: Are you talking about store bought or home made stuff?

Comment: Store bought like m n ms and starburst and candy canes chocolates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's less than 20kg and does not contain meat, [no problem](https://inspection.canada.ca/food-safety-for-consumers/bringing-food-into-canada-for-personal-use/eng/1389630031549/1389630282362). I guess I would avoid saying the words "mincemeat" just in case it's misunderstood.

Canada does not have as strict rules about food imports as the US, since the latter is (with some justification) more worried about terrorist attacks on the food supply.

Comment: Never heard of candy or cookies containing meat i guess that means i can

Comment: @JonH neither had I, but it’s specifically mentioned (and excluded) in the Canadian document. Maybe candied bacon or something like that. Now I’m craving some char siu (BBQ pork)..

Comment: Makes sense bacon is always good.

Answer (score 1):

They say avoid dairy but am sure cookies don’t count. I have got in with 2 big boxes of cookies from india last week into canada. Candies are no problem. Check the immigration declaration form used by CBSA https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/forms-formulaires/e311-eng.pdf